# Jint "unexpected reserved word"

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, class, jint

I am using the Jint interpreter for C# [Jint](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint)

I want to run the following JavaScript code.

```
class User {
  constructor(name) { this.name = name; }
  sayHi() { alert(this.name); }
}
...
```

But I always get an exception "unexpected reserver word in line 1."

What am I doing wrong?

The c# code looks like this:

```
Engine jsEngine = new Engine();
jsEngine.Execute(script);
```

The solution is to build the class like described [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-classes-in-javascript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Jint is a Javascript interpreter for .NET which provides full ECMA 5.1 compliance

The exception you are seeing is because of the `class` keyword, it was introduced in ES6 which Jint does not support yet.